# How to deploy an ASP.NET Web App to Azure with an existing SQL Server database (Azure Data Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, azure

I have an ASP.NET Web App that utilizes a SQL Server database with Entity Framework in Azure Data Studio, along with Docker as a container. I recently published my web app to Azure, and none of my data from my web app migrated to my published web app. I have already added a SQL Server as well in Azure.

Keep in mind I am using Visual Studio 2019 on the **MAC**. I have seen a tutorial online where you can select a service dependency for an azure database, but I can't find that feature on my VS. How would I go about connecting my SQL Server database to my published web app?

Answer (score 0):

In the app service in azure portal, under configuration you can add a connection string to your sql server database

Comment: Thanks for the response! Question, how would that map with my connection string in my appsettings.json? Like in terms of the name, value, and type.

Comment: @MPagan: If you already have the connection string in your `appsettings.json`, there’s no need to configure it on Azure. When you request your connection string, `IConfiguration` will first look in `appsettings.json`, then in the Azure configuration values, which are relayed as environment variables.

Comment: @MPagan: That said, connection strings are frequently stored in a `secrets.json` instead of `appsettings.json`—and especially if they include potentially sensitive information that you don’t want published to e.g. your source code repository. In that case, it’s common to separately define the connection string in each developer’s `secrets.json`, _as well as_ in each Azure App Service’s configuration. Same goes with other secrets, such as e.g. API keys. Alternatively, you can use [Azure App Configuration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-configuration/) to store these centrally.

Comment: @JeremyCaney that makes sense. I'll definitely read up more on the ```secrets.json``` and defining the that information in there. I guess a better question would be how to migrate my local db in azure data studio to azure. I've found info that you need to export the db using an export data tier application, then create the dacpac file, etc. Would that be correct?

Comment: @MPagan: That’s exactly right. [Here’s some documentation that will aid in the import process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import). As an aside, I always found the term _data-tier application_ a bit confusing, but it is in fact what you want to use. That said, I’ve never gone through the export process on Visual Studio for Mac, so YMMV.

Comment: @MPagan: At least [according to this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/getting-started-with-data-tier-applications-in-visual-studio/), however, “the data-tier applications in Visual Studio can only be created on Windows. There are not versions in Mac that support the development of Data-Tier Applications on macOS.”